# How to change status of JsonResponse in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

My API is returning a JSON object on error but the status code is `HTTP 200`:

```py
response = JsonResponse({'status': 'false', 'message': message})
return response
```

How can I change the response code to indicate an error?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

`JsonResponse` normally returns `HTTP 200`, which is the status code for `'OK'`. In order to indicate an error, you can add an HTTP status code to `JsonResponse` as it is a subclass of `HttpResponse`:

```
response = JsonResponse({'status':'false','message':message}, status=500)
```

Answer (score 23):

Return an actual status

```
JsonResponse(status=404, data={'status':'false','message':message})
```

Answer (score 12):

Python built-in http library has new class called [HTTPStatus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html#http.HTTPStatus) which is come from [Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/) onward. You can use it when define a `status`.

```
from http import HTTPStatus
response = JsonResponse({'status':'false','message':message}, status=HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

The value of `HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value` is `500`. When someone read your code it's better define someting like `HTTPStatus.<STATUS_NAME>` other than define an integer value like `500`. You can view all the [IANA-registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) status codes from python library [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html#http-status-codes).

Answer (score 7):

To change status code in `JsonResponse` you can do this :

```
response = JsonResponse({'status':'false','message':message})
response.status_code = 500
return response
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer from Sayse works but it's undocumented. [If you look at the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L563) you find that it passes the remaining `**kwargs` to the superclass constructor, HttpStatus. However in the docstring they don't mention that. I don't know if it's the convention to assume that keyword args will be passed to the superclass constructor.

You can also use it like this:

```
JsonResponse({"error": "not found"}, status=404)
```

I made a wrapper:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

class JsonResponseWithStatus(JsonResponse):
    """
    A JSON response object with the status as the second argument.

    JsonResponse passes remaining keyword arguments to the constructor of the superclass,
    HttpResponse. It isn't in the docstring but can be seen by looking at the Django
    source.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, status=None, encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder,
                 safe=True, json_dumps_params=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(data, encoder, safe, json_dumps_params, status=status, **kwargs)
```