# Django - server code response in JsonResponse

Tags: django

Is it possible to add server response code to JsonResponse ? I need server to reply with 404 in some circumstances.

I have following view

```
def CreateOrAuth(request):
try: 
    username = request.POST.get("username")

    queryset = User.objects.get(username=username)

except Exception as e:
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'user with {} not exist'.format(username)})
```

And I want to add 404 server code here

Comment: please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35059936/3065081

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django json response error status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059916/django-json-response-error-status)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Just pass additional parameter `status` to `JsonResponse`:

```
return JsonResponse({'status': 'user with {} not exist'.format(username)}, status=404)
```